# Access error running Laravel Envoy in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-envoy

I created an envoy file in my Laravel 5.7 app. However, running on my local comp, I got an error:

```
$ envoy run deploy
```

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/user/.ssh/config): failed to
> open stream: Permission denied in
> /home/user/.composer/vendor/laravel/envoy/src/SSHConfigFile.php on
> line 33
> lardeployer@NNN.NN.NN.N's password:

Are that the wrong access on my local system? Which commands do you have to run?